# Subfolder Project C# ASP.NET (Error: Access denied)

Tags: c#, asp.net, project, subdirectory

I publish project A to an IP and publish project B to folder [IP]/subproject. Why would I get a "Access denied" Error, when I try to open [IP]/subproject?

Both are ASP.NET Webprojects by template from Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Do I need to put another line into my webconfigs?

I tried several solutions I found through google.

I run the IIS 6.2 on a Windows R2 2012 Server machine, set the specific user rights for the subfolder/s, even tried to delete the webconfig from root directory or switch the projects.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: you cannot access files outside the root directory of your web app

Comment: Did you set subproject as an Application in your IIS settings?

Comment: problem is i just get one project running through port 80 when i try to setup virtual directory to both projects with the correct "root" folder, within the application pool in IIS